# Make legend stay at bottom matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a graph with about 30 different curves and I want to show them all in the legend.  But it gets too long and they don't all fit.  I want to put them down the bottom, how do I do this?

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(len(data)):
    print(i)
    x1 = data.loc[0][5:-4]
    y1 = data.loc[i][5:-4]
    y1.replace(' ',100.0,inplace=True)
    x = list(reversed(x1))
    y = list(reversed(y1))
    report_num = data.loc[i,'Report No']
    plt.plot(x, y, label = report_num)
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.grid()   
    plt.yticks(yints)
    plt.xticks(x,x,rotation=40)   
    plt.title('Particle Size Distribution Curve - %s'%(report_num))
    plt.legend(loc=1)
```

Comment: Have you tried: `plt.legend(loc='lower center')`?

Comment: This question should be closed as a duplicate of [How to put the legend out of the plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot)